# How to make your own RSA key from bitstream?

Tags: python, rsa, pycryptodome

I have a task to generate private and public RSA keys. However, for private key I am supposed to use a bitstream generated from random generator that I implemented. I don't know how to transform a bitstream into a `Cryto.PublicKey.RSA.RsaKey object`. I need it to use a `key.public_key()` function.

Comment: [`RSA.generate()`](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.generate) accepts a `randfunc` keyword argument.

Comment: Problem is, I already have generated bits and I have to use them

Comment: So create a randfunc() that returns the bits you already have.

Comment: I don't really know  how to do that. Can you explain?